# What are limitations/issues with the "% columns css framework" approach?

Tags: css, grid

I came across this css grid system http://blog.stevendesigns.com/percent-columns-css-framework and found it interesting.

Can you find any reasons or drawbacks to NOT use this approach on a live website?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  Looks pretty slick and lightweight.  I might use this myself. :)

Comment: The only drawback I found so far is the extra markup for the gutters (which the author explained the reasons for that). I would like to know if is there any workaround to avoid that extra markup?

Answer (score 1):

the use of a "grid css framework" is a drawback by itself

- it adds bloat to the HTML by adding a lot of classes
- often times, the HTML itself loses it's structure and semantic meaning
- you are bound by the constructs of the framework, limiting your creativity to what the framework can and cannot do.

Comment: I'm familiar with your points. However, the question is not about  "grid css" is a good or bad thing. It's about any potential design/functionality drawback on that particular framework.